# How do I access 'this' inside of Promise.map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

As we know, `this` below refers to the `window` object. What I would like to know is how I can pass my `this` context in without resorting to the `var self=this;` trick. Any ideas? I tried adding .bind() to the end of line 9 so it reads `}).bind(this);` but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

```
QueueService.prototype.FillCompanyQueue = function(companies) {
    return Promise.map(companies, function (company_batch) {
        var params = {
            Entries: company_batch,
            QueueUrl: Config.get("AWS-Queue.Company")
        };

        return this._sqs.sendMessageBatchAsync(params);
    });
};
```

Edit: I tagged it, but should mention that I am using Bluebird.

Edit: Fixed a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Bluebird's bind function](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#binddynamic-thisarg---promise) :

```
QueueService.prototype.FillCompanyQueue = function(companies) {
    return Promise.resolve(companies).bind(this).map(function(company_batch) {
        var params = {
            Entries: company_batch,
            QueueUrl: Config.get("AWS-Queue.Company")
        };
        return this._sqs.sendMessageBatchAsync(params);
    });
};
```

If you don't need the context outside in the continuation of the promise chain, I'm not sure it's much better than "resorting to the `var self=this;` trick".

Of course, if you're using ES6, you may also simply use an arrow function:

```
QueueService.prototype.FillCompanyQueue = function(companies) {
    return Promise.map(companies, (company_batch) => {
        var params = {
            Entries: company_batch,
            QueueUrl: Config.get("AWS-Queue.Company")
        };
        return this._sqs.sendMessageBatchAsync(params);
    });
};
```

Comment: It's actually incredibly faster to use the `var that=this` trick according to several benchmarks around the net.

Comment: @doogle Are those benchmarks really referring to bluebird ? Links ?

Comment: no they're in reference to the usage of the native `bind` function vs `var self=this;`

Comment: @doogle So they're not relevant, are they ?

Comment: If we're talking about bluebird's `bind` specifically, then no. Though they might be depending on how `bind` is implemented by bluebird. Just something to keep in mind either way.

Comment: Works perfectly. I've only checked out ES6 from afar, but I'm excited to see what it brings to the table.

I would like to see the benchmarks of the Bluebird implementation vs `var that=this;`

Comment: @sean Here's a benchmark for native bind vs self=this http://jsperf.com/var-self-this-vs-function-bind

Answer (score 0):

`}).bind(this);` is binding the promise, not the map callback, try `}.bind(this));`

This is however just an ES5 convention of `var self = this;`

```
QueueService.prototype.FillCompanyQueue = function(companies) {
    return Promise.map(companies, function (company_batch) {
        var params = {
            Entries: company_batch,
            QueueUrl: Config.get("AWS-Queue.Company")
        };

        return this._sqs.sendMessageBatchAsync(params);
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: Bluebird has a bind function : https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#binddynamic-thisarg---promise